# Two multi-variable limit problems

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{2x^2y}{x^4+3y^2}$$

I'm getting that the limit DNE because using $(0,y)\to(0,0)$ it is $0$ but for $(x,x^2)\to(0,0)$ it is $1/2$. Since $0$ does not equal $1/2$ the limit does not exist.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{2x^2+y^2}$$

I'm getting that the limit does not exist because using $(0,y)\to(0,0)$ it is $0$ but $(x,x^2)\to(0,0)$ it is $1$. Since $1$ does not equal $1$ the limit does not exist.

Can someone check my answers and tell me if my reasoning is correct?
Thanks!

Comment: DNE = doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not saying that

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're right, from showing that you can say that the limit does not exists, from more you can say this in terms of the formal definition of a limit, but, with this approach it's enought to say that the limit does not exists